# selected the last inserted id in select query using php

Tags: php, mysql

i was inserted last_id in database at the same time i want to select the last_id in another redirect page.. i was trying the select query but it not coming the last_id... any idea for this

index.php

```
    // this code is inserted the last_id
 <?php  
      $last_id = mysql_insert_id();
   ?>
```

model.php

```
 <? php
    $sql=("SELECT * FROM facility where last_id='".$last_id.'" ");
 ?>
```

kindly give me any idea for this.. thank you

Comment: We need to know your data structure.  `$last_id` is the last *autoincrement value* from your table - but the column could be called *anything*.  What is your table structure (column names) for `facility`?

Comment: `mysql_insert_id();` is only any use directly AFTER an INSERT has been executed. It returns the Auto incremement ID of the row just INSERTED

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Your SELECT query is badly quoted use `$sql = "SELECT * FROM facility where last_id= '$last_id' ");

Comment: `$sql = ("SELECT * FROM facility where last_id = '$last_id' ");`

Comment: facility table colum name is last_id